# Цикл for и объекты

Tags: javascript

Сделайте цикл, который выводит весь массив persons, но только Имя и Фамилию каждой персоны. Используйте вложенный for для вывода полей персоны, и проверку на то, что ключ - имя или фамилия, а не что-то другое.
Имеются данные

```
    var a = {
    name: "Ivan",
    surname: "Ivanov",
    age: 28,
}
var b = {
    name: "Ivan2",
    surname: "Ivanov2",
    age: 29,
}
var c = {
    name: "Ivan3",
    surname: "Ivanov3",
    age: 30,
}
var persons = [a,b,c]
```

Подскажите как дальше делать

Comment: у вас весь алгоритм в задаче расписан ведь. первый цикл по массиву. второй цикл по полям объекта. далее проверить имена полей и вывести их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = {
    name: "Ivan",
    surname: "Ivanov",
    age: 28,
}
var b = {
    name: "Ivan2",
    surname: "Ivanov2",
    age: 29,
}
var c = {
    name: "Ivan3",
    surname: "Ivanov3",
    age: 30,
}
var persons = [a,b,c];

for (var person of persons) {
    var name = '';
    var surname = '';

    for (var key in person) {
        if (key === 'name') name = person[key];
        else if (key === 'surname') surname = person[key];
        else continue;
    }

    console.log(`Person: ${name} ${surname}`);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]